# Failed to get scheduler location from state manager Heron Tutorial

Tags: heron

I'm working through the heron tutorial found here: https://apache.github.io/incubator-heron/docs/getting-started/'

I didn't get very far before I encountered this error:

```
$: heron activate local WindowedWordCountTopology

[2019-02-01 15:55:11 +0000] [INFO]: Using cluster definition in /home/<my-user>/.heron/conf/local
[2019-02-01 15:55:11 +0000] [ERROR]: Failed to get scheduler location from state manager
[2019-02-01 15:55:11 +0000] [ERROR]: Failed to activate topology: WindowedWordCountTopology
```

I'm very new to Heron. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Which version of Heron you are using? And the "heron submit" command succeeded before "heron activate"?

Comment: heron.build.git.revision : 68643ed6b880c0eb34a9704a546d5f482f517575
heron.build.git.status : Clean
heron.build.host : ci-server-01
heron.build.time : Tue Feb 13 06:28:20 UTC 2018
heron.build.timestamp : 1518503300000
heron.build.user : release-agent1
heron.build.version : 0.17.5

Comment: And yes, the submit command succeeded

Comment: Hmm. can you try to submit without the --deploy-deactivated option? Also, do you have this directory on the machine: ~/.herondata/repository/state/local/schedulers/WindowedWordCountTopology?

Comment: I met the same problem and it turns out to be the inconsistency of host.
See the answer by maosongfu at https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/issues/822 Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer. It is too long for comment, so I have to create an answer....

Hard to tell the issue so far, this is the expected output with almost latest code fyi.

```
$ ~/.heron/bin/heron submit local   ~/.heron/examples/heron-streamlet-examples.jar   org.apache.heron.examples.streamlet.WindowedWordCountTopology   WindowedWordCountTopology --deploy-deactivated
[2019-02-05 15:09:53 -0800] [INFO]: Using cluster definition in /Users/<user>/.heron/conf/local
Feb 05, 2019 3:09:54 PM org.apache.heron.streamlet.impl.StreamletImpl defaultNameCalculator
INFO: Calculated stage Name as consumer1
[2019-02-05 15:09:54 -0800] [INFO]: Launching topology: 'WindowedWordCountTopology'
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Initalizing RoundRobinPacking. CPU default: 1.000000, RAM default: ByteAmount{1.0 GB (1073741824 bytes)}, DISK default: ByteAmount{1.0 GB (1073741824 bytes)}, RAM padding: ByteAmount{2.0 GB (2147483648 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal: container CPU hint: 3.000, RAM hint: ByteAmount{-1 bytes}, disk hint: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal finalized: container#1 CPU: 3.000000, RAM: ByteAmount{4.0 GB (4294967296 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal finalized: container#2 CPU: 3.000000, RAM: ByteAmount{4.0 GB (4294967296 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Initalizing RoundRobinPacking. CPU default: 1.000000, RAM default: ByteAmount{1.0 GB (1073741824 bytes)}, DISK default: ByteAmount{1.0 GB (1073741824 bytes)}, RAM padding: ByteAmount{2.0 GB (2147483648 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal: container CPU hint: 3.000, RAM hint: ByteAmount{-1 bytes}, disk hint: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal finalized: container#1 CPU: 3.000000, RAM: ByteAmount{4.0 GB (4294967296 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.packing.roundrobin.RoundRobinPacking: Pack internal finalized: container#2 CPU: 3.000000, RAM: ByteAmount{4.0 GB (4294967296 bytes)}, disk: ByteAmount{14.0 GB (15032385536 bytes)}.  
[2019-02-05 15:09:55 -0800] [INFO]: Successfully launched topology 'WindowedWordCountTopology' 


$ ~/.heron/bin/heron activate local     WindowedWordCountTopology[2019-02-05 15:10:08 -0800] [INFO]: Using cluster definition in /Users/<user>/.heron/conf/local
[2019-02-05 15:10:09 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.heron.spi.utils.TMasterUtils: Topology command ACTIVATE completed successfully.  
[2019-02-05 15:10:09 -0800] [INFO]: Successfully activate topology: WindowedWordCountTopology
```

For "local", the topology state data is stored in  ~/.herondata/repository/state/local//. In your case, you may check if this file is created and contains correct information: ~/.herondata/repository/state/local/schedulers/WindowedWordCountTopology